# Switch and case attribute in ZK tag?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, zk, zul

Here's an example:

```
<zk switch="${each}">

    <zk case="1">
        <hbox spacing="0">
            <textbox
                value="@bind(processChecklistBean.processCheckListDesc)" />
            <image
                src="/resource/image/greenbar-bar.gif" style="cursor:pointer"
                onClick="@command('showPickModalWindow',folderProcessObject = processChecklistBean)" />
        </hbox>
    </zk>
    <zk case="2">
        <hbox spacing="0">
            <textbox
                value="@bind(processChecklistBean.folderProcessChecklistRecord.checklistComment)" />

            <image
                src="/resource/image/greenbar-bar.gif" style="cursor:pointer"
                onClick="@command('showCommentPickDialog',folderProcessObject = processChecklistBean)">
            </image>
        </hbox>
    </zk>
                            </zk
```

Can anyone tell me :

1. Why use this two attribute  `switch` and `case`?
2. In which case the switch and case attribute prefer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are aware of Java `Switch` Case you wilt easily understand why here this is used Just check this [when-to-use-a-switch-statement-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103080/when-to-use-a-switch-statement-in-java)

Here if you will use `if/else` its bit complicated and it will check each condition while in Switch case loop will be automatically break. Like if `case="1"` satisfy current loop will break and it will not go forward and loop will again start this is a advantage