# Using arrays in switch case java

Tags: java

I have code where what a switch statement is testing for depends on an array variable:

```
String shuff = Import.shuffle();
String[] form = new String[95];
for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++)
{
    form[i] = Format.shuffle(shuff, i);
}
switch(str)
{
case "a":
    x = 6;
    break;
case "b":
    x = 16; 
    break;
case "c":
    x = 23;
    break;
//So on and so forth
}
```

What I want to do is take the array form[] and use it as the case:

```
String shuff = Import.shuffle();
String[] form = new String[95];
for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++)
{
    form[i] = Format.shuffle(shuff, i);
}
switch(str)
{
case form[0]:
    x = 6;
    break;
case form[1]:
    x = 16; 
    break;
case form[2]:
    x = 23;
    break;
//So on and so forth
}
```

But when I try this, it gives the error "case expressions must be constant expressions". Two options to solve this come to mind, but I don't know how to do either.
1. use the array in the switch case somehow
2. use some sort of method that would look like this...

```
String shuff = Import.shuffle();
String[] form = new String[95];
for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++)
{
    form[i] = Format.shuffle(shuff, i);
}
switch(str)
{
case form[0].toString():
    x = 6;
    break;
case form[1].toString():
    x = 16; 
    break;
case form[2].toString():
    x = 23;
    break;
//So on and so forth
}
```

Is there any way to do either?

The Import.shuffle method takes a text file with 95 lines (each line being one character) and strings it together and Format.shuffle puts each of the original lines into individual array variables.

I can't convert this into an if else if chain because it's a 95 case switch (edit)

Comment: or use java 1.7/1.8. They support string in switch.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev But it is not the only problem as pointed by Alexis King

Answer (score 6):

You could find the index of `str` within `form`, then switch based on the index. For example:

```
String shuff = Import.shuffle();
String[] form = new String[95];
for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++)
{
    form[i] = Format.shuffle(shuff, i);
}
int index=Arrays.asList(form).indexOf(str);
switch(index)
{
case 0:
    x = 6;
    break;
case 1:
    x = 16; 
    break;
case 2:
    x = 23;
    break;
//So on and so forth
}
```

However, neither of your proposed solutions will work because, when the code is compiled, the compiler needs to know exactly what each `case` value is instead of just knowing that it is in a variable. I'm not sure the exact reasons, but it may be for optimization or for making sure cases are not duplicated (which will compile incorrectly, IIRC). The bottom line is that `form[0]` is not a constant and the compiler wants a constant.

Comment: Good Idea! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Java's `switch` statement *requires* that `case` labels be constant expressions. If your code does not work with that restriction, you'll need to use `if...elseif...else` constructions instead.

See [§14.11 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> *`SwitchLabel`*`:`
>      `case`*`ConstantExpression`*`:`
>      `case`*`EnumConstantName`*`:`
>      `default :`

Comment: The problem with that is its a 95 case switch

Comment: @stealth9799 What kind of action do you have to perform ?

Comment: @stealth9799 If you're seriously attempting to use a 95-case switch, there are probably better ways to accomplish that problem.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, `Java` requires constant expressions in cases on its `switch` statements.

You might need to design the structure better. I noticed that you are making a variable assignment on x, on each case. If this is your real code, you could possible map `x` possible values in a `Map`, or you could even maped them based on the index, in an int array in order to be possible to retrieve it even faster (with `O(1)` complexity).

Examples:

```
//With maps - based on string values
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
values.put(form[0], 6);
values.put(form[1], 16);
values.put(form[2], 23);
//....
x = (int) values.GetValue(str); //str value is your indexer here.


//With arrays, based on indexes
int[] values = new int[] {6, 16, 23/*,...*/};
x = values[i]; // i is your indexer here.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this you will have to use a cascade of if/else.   It would be no less efficient than what you imagine the switch statement to be.  So:

```
if      (str.equals(form[0])) { x = 6; }
else if (str.equals(form[1])) { x = 16; }
else if (str.equals(form[2])) { x = 23; }
```

Takes many less lines of source as well.

Comment: You're taking a bit of a shortcut here.  You're placing the `if` statements on one line as opposed to spreading them out.  Also, for enough statements in a `switch` statement, [it can turn out to be more efficient.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158792/1079354)

Comment: The reason it is more efficient is why the case conditions must be constant... to create a jump table. If you use the java 7/8 string variant it compiles like a cascaded if/else .