# Is if-else better than try-catch in this particular scenario, performance wise? Which way is the best practice?

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript, if-statement, try-catch

I've a json, I need to check a few values and perform a certain task, say this is my json,

```
s = {
    "d": {
      "f": {
        "g": 1
      }
    }
  }
```

and the keys d,f and g might or might not be present, and if g == 1, I need to perform a certain task. So, which of the following gives me better performance.

if-else way of doing this

```
if(s.d && s.d.f && s.d.f.g && s.d.f.g ==1)
{
    doSomeJob();
}
else
{
    doSomeOtherJob();
}
```

try-catch way of doing this

```
try{
if(s.d.f.g ==1)
{
    doSomeJob();
}
}catch(e){
    doSomeOtherJob();
}
```

Comment: `try` - `catch` is almost never going to perform better than simple tests. Some optimizing runtimes will not even attempt to optimize functions with exception handlers. However in most cases it won't make a significant difference to the way your program works.

Comment: I am also with understanding that try/catch blocks are more expensive than if/else statements

Comment: Compare them on https://jsperf.com/

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-javascript/9781449382308/ch04.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case vs If Else If: Which is more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158759/case-vs-if-else-if-which-is-more-efficient)

Answer (score 1):

The thing with `try-catch`. Is that it always attempts to get through the code inside the `try`, and if that doesn't work, it has to reroll everything inside the `try` back to the start of the `try`. 
Only after rerolling, it'll enter the `catch`. This makes using a `try-catch` much slower.

If there is instead a condition (like an if-else statement) at the start. And the statement is false, then it doesn't have to go through the `if`, or the rest of the if-statement at all.

That's where it's more useful to use an `if-else` statement, and why you rather want the `try-catch` to be as short as needed.

Comment: `s = 5; try{s = s+10; undefined['12']}catch(e){console.log(s)}` This piece of code printed 15, so try-catch was not rerolling everything executed in the try block