# Difference between JVM's LookupSwitch and TableSwitch?

Tags: java, bytecode, jasmin

I have some difficulty to understand LookUpSwitch and TableSwitch in Java bytecode.

If I understand well, both LookUpSwitch and TableSwitch correspond to the `switch` statement of Java source? Why one JAVA statement generates 2 different bytecodes?

Jasmin documentation of each:

- [LookupSwitch](https://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref--41.html)
- [tableswitch](https://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref-tableswi.html)
- [both](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/instructions.html)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The difference is that

- *lookupswitch* uses **a table with keys and labels**
- *tableswitch* uses **a table with labels only**.

When performing a **tableswitch**, the int value on top of stack is directly used as an index into the table to grab the jump destination and perform the jump immediately. The whole lookup+jump process is an **O(1) operation**, that means it's blazing fast.

When performing a **lookupswitch**, the int value on top of the stack is compared against the keys in the table until a match is found and then the jump destination next to this key is used to perform the jump. Since a lookupswitch table always **must be sorted** so that keyX < keyY for every X < Y, the whole lookup+jump process is a **O(log n) operation** as the key will be searched using a binary search algorithm (it's not necessary to compare the int value against all possible keys to find a match or to determine that none of the keys matches). O(log n) is somewhat slower than O(1), yet it is still okay since many well known algorithms are O(log n) and these are usually considered fast; even O(n) or O(n * log n) is still considered a pretty good algorithm (slow/bad algorithms have O(n^2), O(n^3), or even worse).

The decision which instruction to use is made by the compiler based upon the fact how *compact* the switch statement is, e.g.

```
switch (inputValue) {
  case 1:  // ...
  case 2:  // ...
  case 3:  // ...
  default: // ...
}
```

The switch above is perfectly compact, it has no numeric "holes". The compiler will create a tableswitch like this:

```
 tableswitch 1 3
    OneLabel
    TwoLabel
    ThreeLabel
  default: DefaultLabel
```

The pseudo code from the Jasmin page explains this pretty well:

```
int val = pop();                // pop an int from the stack
if (val < low || val > high) {  // if its less than <low> or greater than <high>,
    pc += default;              // branch to default 
} else {                        // otherwise
    pc += table[val - low];     // branch to entry in table
}
```

This code is pretty clear on how such a tableswitch works. `val` is `inputValue`, `low` would be 1 (the lowest case value in the switch) and `high` would be 3 (the highest case value in the switch).

Even with some holes a switch can be compact, e.g.

```
switch (inputValue) {
  case 1:  // ...
  case 3:  // ...
  case 4:  // ...
  case 5:  // ...
  default: // ...
}
```

The switch above is "almost compact", it only has a single hole. A compiler could generate the following instruction:

```
 tableswitch 1 6
    OneLabel
    FakeTwoLabel
    ThreeLabel
    FourLabel
    FiveLabel
  default: DefaultLabel

  ; <...code left out...>

  FakeTwoLabel:
  DefaultLabel:
    ; default code
```

As you can see, the compiler has to add a *fake case for 2*, `FakeTwoLabel`. Since 2 is no real value of the switch, `FakeTwoLabel` is in fact a label that changes code flow exactly where the default case is located, since a value of 2 should in fact execute the default case.

So a switch doesn't have to be perfectly compact for the compiler to create a tableswitch, yet it should at least be pretty close to compactness. Now consider the following switch:

```
switch (inputValue) {
  case 1:    // ...
  case 10:   // ...
  case 100:  // ...
  case 1000: // ...
  default:   // ...
}
```

This switch is nowhere near compactness, it has more than hundred times more *holes than values*. One would call this a sparse switch. The compiler would have to generate **almost thousand fake cases** to express this switch as a tableswitch. The result would be a huge table, blowing up the size of the class file dramatically. This is not practical. Instead it will generate a lookupswitch:

```
lookupswitch
    1       : Label1
    10      : Label10
    100     : Label100
    1000    : Label1000
    default : DefaultLabel
```

This table has only 5 entries, instead of over thousand ones. The table has 4 real values, O(log 4) is 2 (log is here log to the base of 2 BTW, not to the base of 10, since computer operate on binary numbers). That means it takes the VM at most two comparisons to find the label for the inputValue or to come to the conclusion, that the value is not in the table and thus the default value must be executed. Even if the table had 100 entries, it would take the VM at most 7 comparisons to find the correct label or decide to jump to the default label (and 7 comparisons is a lot less than 100 comparisons, don't you think?).

So it's nonsense that these two instructions are interchangeable or that the reason for two instructions has historical reasons. There are two instructions for two different kind of situations, one for switches with compact values (for maximum speed) and one for switches with sparse values (not maximum speed, yet still good speed and very compact table representation regardless of the numeric holes).

Comment: `n*log(n)` is larger than `n` for any `n` greater than the base of the log, which I believe would typically be significantly smaller than the size of `n` which we're evaluating; i.e. `O(n)` would be considered *better* than `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @FauxFaux: Thanks for the info, I have corrected the reply accordingly.

Comment: More precisely, it javac 8 gives a weight of 3 for time complexity, and 1 for space complexity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31032054/895245

Comment: "log is here log to the base of 2 BTW, not to the base of 10, since computer operate on binary numbers" - I don't think the binary number system plays any role here. It's just that the searched collection is halved each time and therefore the base of the log is 2.

Comment: just wanted to say that `tableswitch` is not O(1), at least not in practice, it behaves linearly according to some tests.
See here https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire-jlibtorrent/pull/62#issuecomment-162265142

Comment: @Gubatron Sorry, but your method of benchmarking is invalid.You are not even using the lookup result causing the JIT compiler to partly optimize the entire lookup away. If you do it correctly, there is hardly any difference between a lookup 0-9 and a lookup 0-99. And the reason why a table lookup is faster is no surprise either: A memory lookup into a table that can even fit into the 1st level cache of your CPU is naturally ultra fast. Code jumps are never that fast, especially not if the CPU cannot predict them (switches are usually unpredictable for CPUs, contrary to if/else tests in code).

Comment: @Gubatron Here are two corrected benchmarks. Lookup `0-9`: https://ideone.com/cg0cuW and lookup `0-99`: https://ideone.com/fsEHCN . See online runtimes. First has `50 ms` and `1181 ms` and second has `50 ms` and `1215 ms` on my last run. How would that be O(n)? O(n) means it would have to be 10 times slower. Last run on my system with `NUM_INDEXES` of `100000` (ten times more indices than above which must not run longer than 5 seconds on the hosting service!) are `685 ms` and `12168 ms` for `0-9` and `680 ms` and `12515 ms` for `0-99` (keep in mind, there are always fluctuations).

Comment: well, in practice it's certainly not O(1), and worse than O(n) :)
If you have lots of cases that won't fit in your CPU go for the arrays I say, which was the case for our library.

Comment: @Gubatron The switching algorithm itself is O(1). If it gets slower on a system, then this is caused by limitations of that system (e.g. code cache sizes of the CPU). Deciding where to branch happens in O(1) time, always, it's just the branch that can be slow (if it's a cache miss). A more detailed explanation can be found at your own Github link above (see last comment). Here's a version with 1000: https://ideone.com/xHeSfK and it's only marginally slower. Growing code cannot be more O(1) than that; **it's usually only data that grows, not code!**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With your comments I got this code - https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/org/apache/bcel/internal/generic/SWITCH.java

Answer (score 18):

**How `javac` 1.8.0_45 decides what to compile `switch` to?**

To decide when to use which, you could use the `javac` choice algorithm as basis.

We know that the source of `javac` is in the `langtools` repo.

Then we grep:

```
hg grep -i tableswitch
```

and the first result is [langtools/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/30db5e0aaf83/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java#l1153):

```
// Determine whether to issue a tableswitch or a lookupswitch
// instruction.
long table_space_cost = 4 + ((long) hi - lo + 1); // words
long table_time_cost = 3; // comparisons
long lookup_space_cost = 3 + 2 * (long) nlabels;
long lookup_time_cost = nlabels;
int opcode =
    nlabels > 0 &&
    table_space_cost + 3 * table_time_cost <=
    lookup_space_cost + 3 * lookup_time_cost
    ?
    tableswitch : lookupswitch;
```

Where:

- `hi`: maximum case value
- `lo`: minimum case value

So we conclude that it takes into consideration both the time and space complexity, with a weight of **3** for the time complexity.

TODO I don't understand why `lookup_time_cost = nlabels` and not `log(nlabels)`, since a `tableswitch` could be done in O(log(n)) with binary search.

Bonus fact: C++ compilers also make an analogous choice between an O(1) jump table and O(long(n)) binary search: [Advantage of switch over if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement)

Comment: +1 because this helped me figure out how to implement switch instructions in my own JVM language compiler

Comment: O(log(n)) time need never be better, there are always some multiplicators, so that c1*n < c2*log(n) can happen for n<java chooses scan and c3*1 < c2*log(n) for n>=java chooses index. But index can be waste of space.

Answer (score 6):

[Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10) describe the difference. "The tableswitch instruction is used when the cases of the switch can be efficiently represented as indices into a table of target offsets." The specification describes the more details.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it is mostly historical, due to some specific binding of Java bytecode to underlying machine code (e.g. Sun's own CPU).

The `tableswitch` is essentially a computed jump, where destination is taken from a lookup table. By contrast, `lookupswitch` requires comparison of each value, basically an iteration trough table elements until matching value is found.

Obviously those opcodes are interchangeable, but based on values, one or the other could be faster or more compact (e.g. compare set of keys with large gaps in between and a sequential set of keys).

Comment: The Scala 2.13 compiles some Match-Case statements as `tableswitch`, some as `lookupswitch` and some as "nested" If statements.