# Java switch case fall through

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a switch case in Java like this:

```
switch(int example)
{
   case 1: //Do different
      break;
   case 2: //Do different 
      break;
   /** For int more than 2, then I need
       for it to do something same.
   */
   case 3://Do different and case6
      break;
   case 4://Do different and case6
      break;
   case 5://Do different and case6
      break;
   case 6:
      break;
}
```

What is an elegant way to do this, sans having a special case 6 function that case 3-5 calls? (I use int here, but that is an example, so I can't use `if(int >2)`)

Answer (score 3):

A switch can't really do exactly what you are asking out of the box. You can construct something like this with a nested switch though:

```
outer_switch: switch (example) {

    case 1: System.out.println("1");
            break;

    case 2: System.out.println("2");
            break;

    default: {
        switch (example) {

            case 3: System.out.println("3");
                    break;

            case 4: System.out.println("4");
                    break;

            case 5: System.out.println("5");
                    break;

            case 6: System.out.println("6");
                    break;

            default: break outer_switch;
        }

        System.out.println("not 1 nor 2");
    }
}
```

Note the labeled break on `outer_switch` which is a way to circumvent the shared code if `example` does not meet any of the inner cases.

Answer (score 2):

One way I could think of is to move your code to different functions. Something like this.

```
void case1(){
    // do something
}
...
void case3(){
   // do something
    case6();
}
...
void case6(){
   // do something
}

// This switch is in some other method.
switch(int example)
{
   case 1: //Do different
      case1();
      break;
   ...
   case 3://Do different and case6
      case3(); //internally calls case 6
      break;
   ...
   case 6:
      case6();
      break;
}
```

Or you can even have different methods for each case and call `case3()` and `case6()` methods in the `case 3:`. Either way, the methods solutions would work, and IMHO, it would be a bit more elegant and multiple `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's elegant, but one way would be to have two `switch` blocks:

```
switch(int example)
{
   case 1: //Do different
      break;
   case 2: //Do different 
      break;
   case 3:
      // Do whatever
      break;
   case 4:
      // Do whatever
      break;
   case 5:
      // Do whatever
      break;
}

switch(int example)
{
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
      // Do whatever (case 3-5 fall through)
      break;
}
```

Comment: case 3 shouldn't run case 4 nor 5, but 6 only. Thank you though.

Comment: @Secret In the second `switch` statement, you aren't doing anything in case 3 to case 5.  They simply make it fall through to case 6.

Comment: Oh yeah I was bit blind there. =) Radiodef's answer I feel is  more compact, but this is the safest since we don't run default.

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is not pretty it's probably going to give you decent performance. Your other obvious option is an if-elseif-else statement. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement) for why switch might be the best option, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621083/why-does-java-switch-on-ordinal-ints-appear-to-run-faster-with-added-cases?rq=1) to see what performance issues you might run into with large switch statements in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This might also be a solution to what you want to achieve:

```
       switch(example){
            case 1:
                System.out.println(example);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(example);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("I'm case 3");
            case 4:
                if (example == 4){
                    System.out.println("I'm case 4");
                }
            case 5:
                if (example == 5){
                    System.out.println("I'm case 5");
                }
            case 6:
                System.out.println("I'm in extra case " + example);
                break;
        }
```

The idea is that you add an extra condition check to let your code fall through all the branches without executing unnecessary ones.