# Java switch statement with two cases or if statement?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, switch-statement

Hello
Out of interest, when programming in java, would it be more economical to use an if statement or a switch statement for something that could only have two results.
For example:

```
char c = 'a';
if (c == 'a') {
   //do something
}
else if (c == 'A') {
   //do something else
}
```

or

```
char c = 'a';
switch (c) {

   case 'a':
      //do something
      break;

   case 'A':
      //do something else
      break;
}
```

Which would be better?

Comment: count the line-number and indentation. I think, for this case it's obvious enough

Comment: If it can only have 2 results wouldn't be better to have only "else" instead of else if?

Comment: This question has already been asked several times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i

Comment: Note that if the purpose of the `if-else` statement is to assign one value or another (but limited to only one of these two possibilities) then the simplest way is to use a ternary operation.

Comment: Performance-wise you're probably not going to see much difference.  In your case, it appears to be more a matter of personal preference. I'd go with the `if/else if` or `if/else` because it's what I write more often for simple cases such as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really depends on the interest of usage. What usually I do is, If my conditions are more (3 or above) I'l go for switch. Otherwise I simply use `if-else-if`.

> Java switch statement with two cases or if statement?

For your case the first is good enough which is **if else**. If there are more cases like that, prefer switch. That increases readability versus ugly good amount of `if else's`.

Answer (score 1):

Go with if else, if you are sure your just have 2 options.
If you're not sure and it's a bigger project you're working on, I'd go with switch case because its easier to add cases if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, with only two values, the if-else statement is faster than the switch statement.
But it is not always true, especially when you have many cases to test.
You will find more information here :

[Why switch is faster than if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705955/why-switch-is-faster-than-if)

PS : One thing i noticed, but maybe it is needed by your code : if the element to test can only have two values, **if-else** should be better than **if-else if**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement is often considered more error prone than an `if-else` i.e. forgetting a `default` case or `break`. In the case of a short condition say two results an `if-else` is probably preferable, it is unlikely there will be any discernible difference in speed.

Aside, *Robert Martin* in *Clean Code* *p37* puts forward a good argument why `switch` statements are not very OOP.