# How to return enum value in java

Tags: java, enums, return

How can I return enums like this?

Before I was returing an int with 0 if no, 1 if yes and 2 if other. But this wasn't good way to do. So how should it be done. My code:

```
class SomeClass{
   public enum decizion{
      YES, NO, OTHER
   }

   public static enum yourDecizion(){
      //scanner etc
      if(x.equals('Y')){
         return YES;
      }
      else if (x.equals('N')){
         return NO;
      }
      else{
         return OTHER;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: on a sidenote, according to java conventions enums should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: An enum is a (special type of) class, so you should declare it as the return type of your method. By the way, it would be better to name it `Decision` (it _is_ a class).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't what the "//scanner etc." does, but the methods return type should be `decizion`:

```java
    public static decizion yourDecizion() { ... }
```

Furthermore, you can add the `Y`, `N`, etc. values to the enum constants:

```java
    public enum decizion{
         YES("Y"), NO("N"), OTHER;
          
         String key;
      
         decizion(String key) { this.key = key; }
     
         //default constructor, used only for the OTHER case, 
         //because OTHER doesn't need a key to be associated with. 
         decizion() { }

         static decizion getValue(String x) {
             if ("Y".equals(x)) { return YES; }
             else if ("N".equals(x)) { return NO; }
             else if (x == null) { return OTHER; }
             else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
    }
```

Then, in the method, you can just do:

```java
    public static decizion yourDecizion() {
        ...
       String key = ...
       return decizion.getValue(key);
    }
```

Comment: Also, you could perhaps use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Personally, I tend to avoid `switch` statements, in order not to break the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Comment: That is indeed a matter of personal opinion. I was merely mentioning the possibility :)

Comment: in JVM switch statements are optimized to be far faster than if statements:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6705977/557153

Comment: @Konstantin Yovkov that might be a good reason, but then I ask myself, why exits the option to use `switch` statements?

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov How does `switch` statement break Open/Closed principle?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin, https://dzone.com/articles/the-power-of-openclosed-principle

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Thank you for the article. But using many `if`s instead of a switch statement doesn't help you in any way, you're still breaking O/C principle and even in a more inefficient way. The idea behind the article was to replace logic from switch statements with abstraction, which would allow you to extend implementations without touching the original code. However this would add extra complexity and the article even points out that its important to know when to use the principle and when not to. Trying to use it every time will only result in code hard to read and maintain

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin, I have to disagree. It improves (a lot!) readability and testability. In my experience I've applied it many times and it doesn't bring extra complexity, but actually it's the other way around - code become simpler and maintainable.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should do something like these, an enum class. Then you can add as many types you want and the method yourDecizion() will return the enum type depending on the given parameter.

```js
public enum SomeClass {

        YES(0),
        NO(1),
        OTHER(2);

    private int code;


    private SomeClass(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static SomeClass yourDecizion(int x) {
        SomeClass ret = null;
        for (SomeClass type : SomeClass.values()) {
            if (type.getCode() == x)
                ret = type;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
class SomeClass{
   public enum decizion {
      YES, NO, OTHER
   }

   public static decizion yourDecizion(){
      //scanner etc
      if(x.equals('Y')){
         return decizion.YES;
      }
      else if (x.equals('N')){
         return decizion.NO;
      }
      else{
         return decizion.OTHER;
      }
   }
}
```

Note: The method return type must be `decizion` instead of `enum` and `decizion` should have an upper case name (as all classes should).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value in below way. Here you have private constructor which will initialize the value you want to set and when the instance method value gets invoked simply return this.key.

```
public class Application {
    enum Day {
        MONDAY("Monday"), TUESDAY("Tuesday");

        String key;

        Day(String str) {
            key = str;
        }

        public String value() {
            return this.key;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Day.MONDAY.value());
    }

}
```