# I cannot process chars

Tags: java, char, dna-sequence

I am writing code that translates a DNA sequence! The program imports a string called shortDNA (for example ATCGGA) and has to translate it (specifically to TAGCCT), but for some reason it gives the shortDNA string that it imports(in this case ATTCGGA)! what is wrong with my code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < shortDNA.length(); i++) {
            char ch = shortDNA.charAt(i);
            if (ch=='A'){
                ch='T';
            }
            else if (ch=='T'){
                ch='A';
            }
            else if (ch=='G'){
                ch='C';
            }
            else if (ch=='C'){
                ch='G';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where do you actually return something?

Comment: @Marvin after this code but this is not the matter

Comment: Consider using `switch case`

Comment: Well, I'd bet it is.

Comment: @guy I don't thing switch case is a good idea! what do you have in mind?

Comment: @Gamio It won't solve your problem, its basically what you did but the compiler improve the performance. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6705977/5168011) (there are many more, search for "if else or switch" in your favorite search engine).

Comment: @guy I checked it out switch has exactly the same problem! I can't understand why

Comment: @Gamio As I said, it won't solve your problem, just good practice.

Comment: And as for your problem, you don't show enough code to solve it as @Marvin said.

Comment: @guy I think I solved it! I built another string which saves the translated sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting a character variable which is discarded, I assume you want to use this character to build a new String.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : dna.toCharArray()) {
    switch (ch) {
        case 'A': sb.append('T'); break;
        case 'T': sb.append('A'); break;
        case 'G': sb.append('C'); break;
        case 'C': sb.append('G'); break;
    }
}
String dna2 = sb.toString();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I proposed at the comments above!