# java conditional on string result of method call

Tags: java, android, java-8

given the following code and alternatives, which would be better from a maintainability and efficiency standpoint. I have existing code and 2 alternatives. After a lot of internet scouring, I haven't found any real answer.

Existing pseudo-java:

```
Object obj = new ValidObject();
if (TextUtils.equals(obj.method(), CONSTANTS.option1){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(obj.method(), CONSTANTS.option2){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(obj.method(), CONSTANTS.option3){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(obj.method(), CONSTANTS.option4){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option5) || TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option6) ){
}
```

*Alternative 1(replace repeated obj.method() with a local variable):*
The premise here would be that repeating a function call is wasteful for the CPU, at the cost of storing a String

```
Object obj = new ValidObject();
String compareString = obj.method();
if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option1){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option2){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option3){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option4){
} else if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option5) || TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option6) ){
}
```

*Alternative 2(replace if with switch, however, lose TextUtils.equals):*
Mainly for readability, but lookup-switch could apparently be faster than if

```
switch(obj.method()){
    case CONSTANTS.option1:break;
    case CONSTANTS.option2:break;
    case CONSTANTS.option3:break;
    case CONSTANTS.option4:break;
    case CONSTANTS.option5:
    case CONSTANTS.option6:break;
}
```

What would the best option of these be, is there another one I haven't thought about?

*PS:*
Obviously, I have omitted code, as any other code wouldn't be relevant. I do not have an if-statement with 5 empty bodies in my code..

Comment: `switch` could be faster: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705955/why-switch-is-faster-than-if

Comment: Why not begin with `if (TextUtils.equals(compareString , CONSTANTS.option1)` and put the `switch` statement in the `else` branch?

Comment: that would suppose that option1 is the most picked option, wouldn't it? That is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Switch is faster if you have more conditions to compare.

Comment: The switch is a better option compared to else if ladder.

Comment: What exactly do you lose when you “lose TextUtils.equals”?

Comment: the equals function, but on investigation of source, it's no big deal. TextUtils.equals uses String.equals if both are instances of String. Else, it loops over chars in the CharSequence