# Jmeter - JSR223 PostProcessor operates on the following ForEach iteration

Tags: foreach, jmeter, jsr223

**Problem**
The JSR223 shifts its processing. On the first ForEach iteration I expect the JSR223 to produce a given value, but I see that expected value on the debug postprocessor of the following interation instead.
Why is this happening?

**Scenario**
I have a set of companies (thread group). Each company has a set of Stores (ForEach #1). Each store has a set of "location groups" (ForEach #2). Each location group has its own type.

[Scenario outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCygr.png)

The location group type is a numeric value, from 1 to 12. Let's say the ForEach controller iterating these location groups produce this sequence of types: 6, 9, 5, 11, 7, 12, 10 and JSR223's code is as follows:

```
if (vars.get("locationGroupType") == "6"){
    log.info("Store:" + vars.get("anUnit"))
    log.info("location group ID:" + vars.get("aLocationGroupId"))
    vars.put("aux", "SIX")
    log.info("location group type:" + vars.get("locationGroupType"))
 }
 if (vars.get("locationGroupType") == "9"){
    log.info("Store:" + vars.get("anUnit"))
    log.info("location group ID:" + vars.get("aLocationGroupId"))
    vars.put("aux", "NINE")
    log.info("location group type:" + vars.get("locationGroupType"))
 }
```

I would expect aux to be SIX on the first iteration, then NINE on the second.

**Output**
This is JSR223's output to console:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RNpC.png)
You can see the store 292 has a location group id of 3803 which has a type value 6. **But this information is NOT correct.**

Request output for location group id 3803, which has a type value of 9:
[location group 3803 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KDYO.png)
Debug postprocessor dump where I can see 'aux' set to SIX:
[debug postprocessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsdBU.png)

Oddly enough, the previous request to 3803 is the one that has the type value 6, and this is where I expect aux to be SIX:
[Response for 3635 where the type value 6 is found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIsYh.png)
And the debug postprocessor for 3635 showing 'aux' to be empty:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBH7o.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use all these values: `6, 9, 5, 11, 7, 12, 10`  it's [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705955/why-switch-is-faster-than-if) to go for [switch statement](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_switch_case) instead of multiple if's.

Isn't it a copy-paste issue and shouldn't your code look like:

```
switch (vars.get(('locationGroupType'))) {
    case '6':
        log.info("Store:" + vars.get("anUnit"))
        log.info("location group ID:" + vars.get("aLocationGroupId"))
        vars.put("aux", "SIX")
        log.info("location group type:" + vars.get("locationGroupType"))
        break
    case '9':
        log.info("Store:" + vars.get("anUnit"))
        log.info("location group ID:" + vars.get("aLocationGroupId"))
        vars.put("aux", "NINE")
        log.info("location group type:" + vars.get("locationGroupType"))
        break
    default:
        log.info('default branch')
        break
}
```

Otherwise I can think of the following reasons:

- JMeter Post-Processor placement matters, i.e. if your have Debug Post-Processor **before** the JSR223 Post-Processor you won't see the variables generated in the JSR223 Post-Processor until next iteration
- JSR223 PreProcessor is executed after each Sampler in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so make sure that it's placed correctly and fired only where it's supposed to fire.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: The code in the JSR223 is more complex than what I mention in my post. The code in the post is only meant to show my problem with the shifting I describe.
The nesting of the elements is properly done. 
ForEach with HTTP Request and JSR223. The HTTP Request has a Regex which is the variable used in the JSR223. JSR223 and HTTP Request are at the same level, HTTP Request comes first.

Thanks for your answer though, I appreciate the time spent in understanding my problem.

Comment: I also have debugs before and after JSR223 and I'm positive I'm looking at them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I describe in my thread was a Jmeter issue. I just tried the same exact script in Jmeter 5.5 and the shifting problem has been resolved.