# Checking for null at initialization

Tags: java, variables, null, initialization

I set a string with a method that can either return any string or `null`.

I want the string to be `""` whenever it's `null`. So i use:

```
String mString = getMyString();
mString = mString==null ? "" : mString;
```

Or (less eficciently, but in one line):

```
String mString = getMyString() == null ? "" : getMyString();
```

Any cleaner way to do this?

EDIT: I've considered using an if statement:

```
String mString = getMyString();
if (mString == null); mString = "";
```

Which one (the 1st or 3rd) would perform faster?

Comment: Move it into the method and never return `null`.

Comment: It's a closed-source method, i do not have acces to it.

Comment: Then ... write your method that calls that method :) What you're doing is fine, and there's literally any number of ways to go about it ... but they all do the same thing.

Comment: It's a could idea to use standard layout on those `if` statements...

Comment: If that's a behavior you want to replicate, and should depend on the string rather than the method, you could consider creating a wrapper class for String that offers the same functionalities, but automatically treats null as "".

Comment: Because of the semicolon after your `if` statement, your String will now **always** be `""`, even if it was not `null` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many errors result in `null`s propagating. It's much better to use an empty string if you mean an empty string. Same for collections. So throw an NPE at the earliest available opportunity. Java SE 7 introduces (a verbose, incorrectly capitalised, poorly located) method for doing this.

```
String mString = java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(getMyString());
```

Comment: what do you mean by _incorrectly capitalised_? I don't think the method is helpful in this case, as it will throw a NPE instead of _fixing_ the value.

Comment: Generally hyphenated words only have the leading path capitalised (if appropriate). Just as well as there is a tendency to remove hyphens - don't want to under up uncoOrdinated. / The value is almost certainly broken. Fixing hides the problem, which is an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea to hide the problem (in most cases). As far as the method name goes, it perfectly fits the Java naming conventions, imho. Class names start with a capital letter, and methods with a lower-case letter and then use camel case.

Comment: this solution is only applicable if the user us using Java 7

Comment: @user1428716 There will be no further public supported updates of Java SE 6, so 7 is a jolly good idea. It's only the specific method which requires Java SE 7 - writing equivalent code is not too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really :)

Or you could create another method called `getMyNonNullString` which does it for you - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Like what Brian Roach commented:

If you have control over `getMyString()` implement it in a way that it returns an empty string instead of `null`. Otherwise I also use your first approach (trying to optimize it for branch prediction) :

```
String mString = getMyString();
// if I know getMyString() might return null and I can't change it:
mString = mString != null ?  mString : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Apache Common's:

`StringUtil.isBlank(strVariable);`

Its a nice way to standardize projects, especially large ones. Otherwise you have to repeat your home cooked logic everywhere.

The following is a link for your reference: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: I used to code on a large project (10k classes)... and this was a really nice to use.

Answer (score 1):

The second is definitely not the way to go since it is not the same.

Don't do any of these though.  Write a convenience function like the below once and statically import it so that the intent is clear.

```
public static @Nonnull String nullToEmptyString(@Nullable String s) {
  return s != null ? s : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the 3rd form. Performance wise there shouldn't be any noticeable difference.

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest a different approach. I don't have JAVA 7 due to MACOSX restriction yet so if there is syntax error , please guide me through. Comments Welcome

This is based on the question I had asked on Stacoverflow error : [Why is the switch statement faster than if else for String in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836055/switch-statement-in-java-7)

```
 The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from switch statements that   
 use "String objects" than from chained if-then-else statements.
```

So , --> Switch Statement would be more efficient than if-else block. The performance with try-catch is debatable

```
   String str = getMyString(); // only one call

   try {
    switch (str) {
      default:   break;
    }

    } catch(NullpointerException e){

      str="";//Null means Str is null
    }
```

Comment: down voter care to explain ?

Comment: Just guessing at potential reasons here: (a) using exceptions as control flow in this way is definitely not cleaner code (and are likely [much slower](http://stackoverflow.com/a/567593/836214); (b) a switch statement with strings is unlikely to be more efficient if there is only a single case.