# Why is a single "if" slower than "switch"?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the relative performance difference of if/else versus switch statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i)

Given the following two methods:

```
public static int useSwitch(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

public static int useIf(int i) {
    if (i == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

testing shows that the `switch` executes marginally faster (1.4 nanoseconds per call on my machine) than the `if` version.

I had always believed that the benefit of a switch didn't kick in until at least a few `ifs` could be avoided,

Why is `switch` faster than a single `if`?

Comment: Do you know how they look compiled? Maybe you can find your answer there.

Comment: @user1306322- You'd have to look even deeper to investigate how the JVM was interpreting or compiling that bytecode.  The first code will probably use a `lookupswitch` or `tableswitch` instruction, while the second will use normal jumps.  It's all up to the JVM to make them work fast.

Comment: Could you post your benchmarking code?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan testing code compares `nanoTime()` for `for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) x += useIf(i)` (`x` is asserted)

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2086550/1180720

Comment: @Bohemian Did you control for issues such as, for example, which test is done first? There are a lot of details that can affect the results of Java micro-benchmarking.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Actually, further testing showed that sometimes the if was faster. My conclusion is that the difference is small for small numbers of `ifs`. Perhaps for larger numbers of `ifs`, changing to switch may be warranted for performance-sensitive code. But we are talking about nanoseconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By checking the bytecode the result is as expected:

**SWITCH**

```
public static useSwitch(I)I
 L0
  ILOAD 0
  TABLESWITCH
    0: L1
    default: L2
 L1
  INVOKESTATIC Tests.a()I
  IRETURN
 L2
  INVOKESTATIC Tests.b()I
  IRETURN
```

**IF**

```
public static useIf(I)I
 L0
  ILOAD 0
  IFNE L1
 L2
  INVOKESTATIC Tests.a()I
  IRETURN
 L1
  INVOKESTATIC Tests.b()I
  IRETURN
```

Now I don't see any particular reason for which one should be slower than the other (not by a significative amount in any case). This is surely something that is related to the specific JVM implementation and how it executes these opcodes. According to common knowledge the `TABLESWITCH` instruction should be slower unless there are enough cases that makes its construction valuable but this is just **common thinking**. Every JVM could implement it differently so this is just speculation.

Are you sure to profiled everything in a consistent way? (by giving time to JVM to warm up, by keeping just results within a confidence range and all the other things that make profiling enough correct to be used)

Comment: I must confess that after running the test many times, *sometimes* the if is faster than the switch. Your comment about there not being any particular reason for a difference reflects what I found with further testing

Answer (score 0):

This type of comparison is analyzed in [If-else vs switch – Which is better?](http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2009/08/if-else-vs-switch-%E2%80%93-which-is-better/).
However, try to compile to native code using gcj and compare obtained results with result from the use of bytecode.