# Is there a difference in the operations of if/else and a switch statement?

Tags: java, performance, switch-statement, if-statement

I'm mostly just curious, is using if/else and a switch statement just a matter of personal preference, or do they actually work differently? Is one more efficient than the other? If they are, why exactly?

Comment: See also the second answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your case more than four, switch-case statement is more effiecient. your case directly jumped. on the other hand if  you use if-else  statement all cases compared until your cases is crossed.