# Differences between IF and SWITCH/CASE in C

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, switch-statement

The question is really simple: in a laboratory class I attended this year, professor presented the `switch/case` statement alongside the classic `if/then/else` statement without saying anything about which one was better in different programming situations.

Which one is better when checking a variable which can have at least 10/15 possible values?

Comment: This is a bit too vague/subjective for this forum, I think.

Comment: `switch` is not nearly as powerful as a chain of `if`s, but it is usually faster. Therefore, you *should* use a `switch` in all situations when you *can* use a `switch`; otherwise, use a chain of `if`s.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Taken literally, I have to object. `switch(variable) { case 0: return; }` would better be written with an `if`. (I agree with the intended meaning, of course.)

Comment: @DanielFischer It becomes more readable when you omit the curlies :-)

Comment: @DanielFischer That's hardly a chain of `if`s, though :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How many links make a chain?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's an excellent question: a lot of people would probably say "two", programmers would likely agree on "one", while  mathematicians would insist on "zero or more".

Comment: @DanielFischer Google says 100. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_(unit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Breifly (your question is vague), a switch compiles to a *jump table* in assembler and is therefore faster than if / then / else. Note that a switch statement in C has a 'follow-through' feature (google this) which can be circumvented with break statements.

You can only switch on things that evaluate to integral types. In particular this means that you cannot switch on strings: strings are not part of the natural C language in any case.

An if / then / else checks several conditions in succession. Comparison is not restricted to integral types as all you're testing is true (not zero) or false (zero).

That's probably enough to get you started.

Comment: A `switch` is not *necessarily* a jump table. For large types such as `long long`, it may get compiled to a binary search instead.

Comment: True. It's entirely up to the compiler. So long as they obey the standard and permit nasal demons in undefined cases ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When the value to be compared has a type that is amenable to being `switch`'d, and it makes your code more readable, then go ahead and use a `switch`. For example,

```
if (val == 0) {
    // do something
} else if (val == 1) {
    // do something else
} else if (val == 2) {
    // yet another option
} ...
```

is cluttered and hard to maintain compared to a `switch`. Imagine that some day, you don't want to switch on `val` but on `validate(val)`; then you'd need to change all the conditions.

Also, `switch` may be faster than `if`/`else` sometimes, because a compiler may turn it into either a [jump table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) or a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Then again, a compiler *might* do the same to a series of `if`/`else` statements, although that's a more difficult optimization to make because the clauses order might matter and the compiler must be able to detect that it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I think
If then else is better in case only when you have 2 conditions only.
Otherwise its better to use switch case if conditions are more than 2

Comment: ALso look at this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i

Answer (score 1):

`switch` looks better than lots of `if`s. However it only works on numeric expressions (as a `char` is essentially a number, it can still be applied to it, however you cannot use it with strings).

If I may point you to [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html) as it has a nice description of the `switch` statement. Note the opening sentence:

> Switch case statements are a substitute for long if statements that
>   compare a variable to several "integral" values ("integral" values are
>   simply values that can be expressed as an integer, such as the value
>   of a char).

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is better performance-wise too because it can be optimized in various ways by the compiler, depending on whether the values are consecutive. If yes, it can outright use the value as an index to an array of pointers. If not, it can sometimes use a binary search instead of a linear search, when it's faster.