# How do i condense these return statements or avoid the checkstyle error all together?

Tags: java, javafx, return, checkstyle

Currently, I'm working on writing classes for a brick breaker game for my java class. I have a question about a checkstyle error I'm getting for my `public javafx.scene.paint.Color getColor()` method which gets the color of the brick based on how many times it has been hit by the ball.

The checkstyle error says: `Return count is 6 (max allowed for non-void methods/lambdas is 2).` which I assume it means I can only have 2 return statements as opposed to the 6 that I have currently. All of the statements have different returns based on the value of `this.hits` which is what I don't understand. The documentation for it is as follows:

```
public javafx.scene.paint.Color getColor()

The current color to represent this Brick's breakability state.
Returns:There are five possible Colors that can be returned based on 
theBrick's current strength: Color.BLACK if this Brick cannot be 
broken;Color.WHITE if this Brick has been completely broken; and 
Color.RED, Color.YELLOW,Color.GREEN if this Brick will break after 1, 2, 
and 3 more hits, consecutively.
```

And the code:

```
public javafx.scene.paint.Color getColor() {

        if (this.hits == -1) {
            return javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK;

        } else if (this.hits == 0) {
            return javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT;

        } else if (this.hits == 1) {
            return javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED;

        } else if (this.hits == 2) {
            return javafx.scene.paint.Color.YELLOW;

        } else if (this.hits == 3) {
            return javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN;
        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: `Color color = null;  if (this.hits == -1) {  color =  javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK; } /*more if statements*/ return color;`

Comment: @c0der that didn't seem to work. It might have to do with the value of it being `null` in the first place. I'm just not sure how to fix it and i don't want it to return two separate colors, one in the if and the one outside of the if.

Comment: I posted the full method as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following method does the same with one return statement:

```
    public javafx.scene.paint.Color getColor() {

        javafx.scene.paint.Color color = null;

        if (this.hits == -1) {
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK;

        } else if (this.hits == 0) {
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT;

        } else if (this.hits == 1) {
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED;

        } else if (this.hits == 2) {
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.YELLOW;

        } else if (this.hits == 3) {
           color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN;
        }

        return color;
 }
```

Comment: ohh! I see now! I was leaving out `color = ...` inside the if statement so it was leaving the value of `color` as `null`

Comment: While my answer might be easier to follow [Elliott Frisch Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57815771/3992939) offers a better design.

Comment: I saw that and it would work but i think for the assignment im working on it would be a little over the top considering i really don't understand hash maps. Id just be copying and pasting while not really knowing how it works. While Elliot may have a better designed answer, i understand yours much more easily and it fits with the other elements of my assignment much better.

Answer (score 8):

You could populate a `HashMap<Integer, Color>` with your values and use a single return off fetching the value from the `Map`. Like,

```
private static Map<Integer, javafx.scene.paint.Color> COLOR_MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    COLOR_MAP.put(-1, javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
    COLOR_MAP.put(0, javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);
    COLOR_MAP.put(1, javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
    COLOR_MAP.put(2, javafx.scene.paint.Color.YELLOW);
    COLOR_MAP.put(3, javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
}

public javafx.scene.paint.Color getColor() {
    return COLOR_MAP.get(this.hits);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Completing @cOder and @Elliot answers, you can use `switch-case` to improve your code. In your case, using this architecture is faster to run and you don't have to save a `HashMap` into memory to make it work.

```
public javafx.scene.paint.Color getColor() {
    javafx.scene.paint.Color color;
    switch (this.hits) {
        case -1:
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK;
            break;
        case 0:
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT;
            break;
        case 1:
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED;
            break;
        case 2:
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case 3:
            color = javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN;
            break;
        default:
            color = null;
            break;
    }

    return color;
}
```

You can take a look at [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i) because it slightly explains the difference between our 3 answers.

Comment: `switch` is a valid alternation, but you need to implement it so it answers the basic question: how to avoid multiple `return` statements.